# Paypal button subtype

Tags: html, paypal

Can someone please let me know what's the deal with PAYPAL's button subtype, I know it takes one of the two values - "products" or "services" and it's obvious what that means, but I don't understand how this affects the checkout process and more importantly what's happening if the button subtype is left undefined.
The code goes like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="products" />
```

or this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The `button_subtype` is the deprecated field for PayPal Website Payments Standard.

You can simply remove this line of code, and it won't have an impact on your button's payment processing.